# How do I skip tests when using node native test runner with TypeScript/esrun?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, node-test-runner, esrun

I am using the [node test runner](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html#filtering-tests-by-name). have some tests in a small demo file:

```js
import { describe, test } from "node:test";
import assert from "node:assert";

describe("thing", () => {
  test("it works", () => {
    assert.ok(true);
  });
});

describe("this should not be tested", () => {
  test("it works", () => {
    assert.ok(true);
  });
});
```

When I run `node --test-name-pattern="thing" runme.test.mjs` I can see it only tests `thing` and skips `this should not be tested`:

```
▶ thing
  ✔ it works (0.153ms)
▶ thing (1.306708ms)

▶ this should not be tested
  ﹣ it works (0.13525ms) # test name does not match pattern
▶ this should not be tested (0.23425ms)

ℹ tests 2
ℹ suites 2
ℹ pass 1
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 1
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 0.079417
```

Great! I can see `this should not be tested` is skipped!

However I want to use TypeScript for my tests. Using `esrun` and following [the esrun docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@digitak/esrun#cli-parameters-syntax) I am running:

```
esrun runme.test.mjs --test-name-pattern="thing"
```

(yes, this is the same JS file as before, esrun can also run JS files)

However the tests are not skipped:

```
▶ thing
  ✔ it works (0.11725ms)
▶ thing (0.945292ms)

▶ this should not be tested
  ✔ it works (0.040375ms)
▶ this should not be tested (0.100708ms)

ℹ tests 2
ℹ suites 2
ℹ pass 2
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 0.105375
```

**How can I skip tests when using the node native test runner with TypeScript/esrun?**

Answer (score 0):

**Answering my own question to help others**

The correct syntax is mentioned in [the esrun docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@digitak/esrun#other-node-cli-options), but I had missed it:

> You can pass custom options to the node cli by prefixing the option name with "--node", like this:
> esrun --node-max-old-space-size=4096 foo.ts

So to skip tests with the native test runner, use `--node-test-name-pattern`:

```
esrun --node-test-name-pattern="thing" runme.test.mjs

▶ thing
  ✔ it works (0.144791ms)
▶ thing (1.027917ms)

▶ this should not be tested
  ﹣ it works (0.048459ms) # test name does not match pattern
▶ this should not be tested (0.124208ms)

ℹ tests 2
ℹ suites 2
ℹ pass 1
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 1
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 0.124166
```

This also works with TS files (including both `.ts` and `.mts`).